# How do override native DnD ghost image?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I want to change browser's natively logic of DnD ghost image generation. I want to drag real (or clone of real) element instead of screenshot.

I found only how i can override a ghost image to another image (but i want do drag real DOM element, or copy of DOM element) here https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html.

I also looked at DataTransfer docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) and saw that API doesn't have any methods for setting DOM element to ghost.

Any ideas how i can implement that without any libs for most browsers with good performance ?